# Different module.exports pattern in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

Lets assume we are creating simple app with node.js and express (Note App). We want to organize our code and put all controllers in separate folder. so we create a folder and create `index.js` in it. then we add our controllers js files to this folder. Then initialize all controllers in main entry point of `index.js` and then use `require` in `server.js` to access our controllers.(I don't like big, bulky and messy `server.js` files that all logic stick in it!)

All of these sample codes works fine, but I can't understand difference between these code blocks.

1.

```
module.exports.init = function(app){
    console.log("notes controller init.");
};
```

2.

```
function init(app){
    console.log("notes controller init.");
};
module.exports.init = init;
```

3.

```
(function (notesController){
    notesController.init = function(app){
        console.log("notes controller init.");
    };
})(module.exports);
```

4.

```
module.exports = {
    init: function(app){
        console.log("notes controller init.");
        }
    }
```

Is there any difference in performance or loading of these function or something mysterious in JavaScript or just diversity in coding style?

Thanks.

PS.

I am back-end c#  developer who used to hate JavaScript! but I'm trying to understand  nature of this language because of Node.js.  I google a lot about module and exports and prototype and ... in JavaScript but can't find the answer.

Comment: There is indeed difference in performance, but you cannot measure it since it's negligible.

Comment: @zerkms witch one is better?

Comment: You left out `module.exports = { init: function(app){console.log("notes controller init.");}}`

Comment: "Better" from what perspective?

Comment: @zerkms there is always some contracts or convention between programmers. Like the order of public and private methods in csharp or java code file. witch one is more accepted in community? and can we say witch one is not good for some reason?

Comment: @acbabis Thanks, i have update the question and added 4th option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option #1** declares an un-named function and assigns it directly to `module.exports.init`.

**Option #2** creates a locally named function `init` and then assigns that to `module.exports.init`.  As far as `module.exports.init` is concerned, there is no functionality difference at all between #1 and #2.  #2 has created the local symbol `init` that could be used to execute that same function locally as a shortcut.  But, the results of executing `module.exports.init()` would be exactly the same with any of the four options.

**Option #3** creates a local IIFE function scope which allows you to have private variables that your `init` function could use that would survive from one invocation of the method to the next and would even be private within your module (other parts of your module couldn't even access them).  You don't declare any of those private variables, but you could.  Other than that, the execution of `module.exports.init` will again be no different than the previous two options since the exact same function reference is assigned to `module.exports.init` in all three options.

**Option #4** defines a new `export.modules` object and then statically declares one method in that object.  This can be a useful and compact way to define lots of methods that are all exported (this is a common design pattern), but I personally would not use it when only declaring a single exported method because option #1 is just plain simpler.

Any performance differences between these would only be during initialization and are likely so small they would be hard to measure or to find them material.

---

**Which option is best is entirely opinion.**  I personally favor the simplest solution that follows good coding practices and gets the job done.  For me that would be option #1 since there appears to be no reason to have `init` defined locally (option #2) and no reason to have an IIFE for private symbols (option #3).

So, I'd rather not create a named function that isn't used or needed (option #2) and I'd rather not declare an IIFE that isn't being used for any purpose (option #3).

I generally do use option #4 myself if I am declaring multiple exported methods because it is the most compact syntax for doing that.

Comment: Not only is the IEFE not used in the example, but it appears especially superfluous when considering that each module already has its own module scope.

Comment: @Bergi - yep the IIFE is offering privacy from other parts of your own module as privacy is already there from the outside world via the module's function scope.

Comment: @Navid - Added comments on the newly added option #4.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for detail and informative answer!

Comment: @Navid - are you aware that on StackOverflow, if you get your question answered, you should check the green checkmark next to the best answer?  That tells the community that your question has been answered and earns you some reputation points.

Comment: @jfriend00 ,Sorry. I checked the green checkmark last night before sending my latest comment! may be its due to internet/network problem in my ISP and/or in Iran.anyway thanks again.